# retrieving facebook likes via fql for 'non-facebook' objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

basically I am trying to get the total of (facebook) likes for an external object via FQL. I already retrieve the comments for that object via FQL with the xid as identifier.
My problem is that I need an object_id to retrieve the likes which I haven't got. Are the obect_ids only for facebook objects (pics, albums, video etc) or is there something similar for external objects (like the xid for comments)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, got it. It's treated like a link....

SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='URL'

Comment: Is there a way to get total number of likes across entire domain?